# Is there a non probabilistic proof to this linear algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, alternative-proof

I recently solved this problem that was part of the excercises of a combinatorics book, it wasn't a hard problem, provided that I knew I had to use the probabilistic method, which the chapter was on. But I wanted to know if there is a non-probabilisic solution to this problem. Without using anything equivalent to the probabilistic method. The problem is as follows

Given $v_1,\cdots,v_n\in\mathbb R^n$ vectors such that $|v_i|=1$ for every $i$. Prove that there are numbers $a_i=\pm1$ such that

$$|a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n|\leq \sqrt n$$

More over, show that we can also choose the $a_i$ such that

$$|a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n|\geq \sqrt n$$

Comment: "Ideally using only linear algebra." - clearly estimates cannot be proved with linear algebra alone. We will need at least some methods form calculus. What have you tried so far (without probability theory)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's fine, maybe I'll updatethe question, but I meant that I didn't want something equivalent to the probabilistic method

Comment: What about [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310701/komlós-conjecture-upper-bound?noredirect=1) then?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is equivalent to the probabilistic method if I'm not mistaken, right?

Comment: Not really equivalent. It uses more monotonicity of -norms. But yes, there is probability mentioned, but much less than in your solution (do you have a link, by the way?).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The solution you cited is basically my solution. That's the most basic case of the probabilistic method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$, let $s=\operatorname{sign}\langle u,v\rangle$ (with the convention that $\operatorname{sign}(0)=1$). Then
$$
\|u-sv\|^2
=\langle u-sv,u-sv\rangle
=\|u\|^2-2s\langle u,v\rangle+\|v\|^2
\le\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2.
$$
Similarly, $\|u+sv\|^2\ge\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$.

The first part of your problem can therefore be solved by taking $a_1=1$ and
$$
a_i=-\operatorname{sign}\langle a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{i-1}v_{i-1},\,v_i\rangle
$$
for each $i\ge2$, while the second part is solved by taking $a_1=1$ and
$$
a_i=+\operatorname{sign}\langle a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{i-1}v_{i-1},\,v_i\rangle
$$
for each $i\ge2$.